# How to parse a mysql slow query log into something useful?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I have an extensive slow query log which was running for a few weeks. I would like to parse it, which would put the highest occurring queries at the top (with number of executions and average times of execution), and it goes from there in descending order.

What tool/command can I use to accomplish that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out [Percona Toolkit](https://www.percona.com/software/database-tools/percona-toolkit):

mk-query-digest - Parses logs and more. Analyze, transform, filter, review and report on queries.

Answer (score 4):

For a better reading of the slow log I use:

```
mysqldumpslow -s c -t 10 /var/log/mysql_slow_queries.log
```

Edit the path to the slow log.

Sample output:

```
Reading mysql slow query log from /var/log/mysql_slow_queries.log
Count: 1  Time=21.52s (21s)  Lock=0.00s (0s)  Rows=3000.0 (3000), foo@localhost
  SELECT * FROM students WHERE
  (student_grade > N AND student_date < N)
  ORDER BY RAND() ASC LIMIT N
```

Also, calling just the `mysqldumpslow` without any options, would print some useful settings like current query_cache_size, path to slow log, etc.

Answer (score 0):

This script gives a more clear response than the maakit mk-query-digest:

https://github.com/LeeKemp/mysql-slow-query-log-parser/

Answer (score 0):

This online analyzer worked really well for me, and it's free! Just drag and drop your slow query file.

https://www.slowquerylog.com/analyzer

Answer (score 0):

For Windows users!
I created a PowerShell script to parse a set of the logs and save the result into .xlsx

```
<#
1. Run the script.
2. Select one or more slow-query-log files from a file browser.
3. Observe the result in the Excel file (Excel will be opened automatically). Resulting .xlsx file is saved in the same folder as the source slow-query-log file(s).
#>

cls;

if (-not (Get-Module ImportExcel -ListAvailable))
{
    Install-Module ImportExcel -AllowClobber -Force
}
Import-Module ImportExcel -Force

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms


# Select log files for parsing. Choose multiple files if needed with Ctrl or Shift in the file blowser
$FileBrowser = $null
$content = $null

$FileBrowser = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog -Property @{ 
   # InitialDirectory = [Environment]::GetFolderPath('Desktop') 
    InitialDirectory = (New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application).NameSpace('shell:Downloads').Self.Path 
    Title = "Open slow-query-log file(s)"
    Multiselect = $true
   # Filter = 'Documents (*.docx)|*.docx|SpreadSheet (*.xlsx)|*.xlsx'
}
$null = $FileBrowser.ShowDialog()

if (-not $FileBrowser.FileName) {break}

$content = Get-Content $FileBrowser.FileNames

if (-not $content) {break}


# Full file name of Excel report
$ReportFile = $FileBrowser.InitialDirectory+"\slow-query-log-report.xlsx"

Write-Verbose -Verbose -Message  "Report file location: $ReportFile"

try
{
    if (Test-Path $ReportFile)
    {
        Remove-Item $ReportFile -Force -ErrorAction Stop
    }
}
catch
{
    throw
    break
}



##################################
###        MAIN PROCESS        ###
##################################

$QueryProps = @()
$Time = ""
$UserHost = ""
$Id = ""
$QueryTime = ""
$LockTime = ""
$RowsSent = ""
$RowsExamined = ""
$Statement = ""
$NormStatement = ""

# Actual parsing process by fetching each row from the input files content
foreach ($row in $content) 
{

    if ($row -like "# Time*")
    {
        if ($Time)
        { 
            # Prepare normalized SQL statement by replacing actual values in the query string with "?" to identify identical queries
            $NormStatement = $Statement -replace("(\d+|\'.*?\')", "?")

            $Statement = $Statement.Substring( 0, [math]::min($Statement.Length, 16000) ) #cut off a very long string
            $NormStatement = $NormStatement.Substring( 0, [math]::min($NormStatement.Length, 16000) ) #cut off a very long string

            $Props = @{
                "QueryNum"        = 0
                "Time"            = $Time
                "GroupNum"        = 0
                "UserHost"        = $UserHost
                "Id"              = $Id
                "QueryTime"       = $QueryTime
                "LockTime"        = $LockTime
                "RowsSent"        = $RowsSent
                "RowsExamined"    = $RowsExamined
                "Statement"       = $Statement
                "NormStatement"   = $NormStatement
            }
            $QueryProps += New-Object PSObject -Property $Props
        }
            
        $Statement = ""
        
        $Time = ($row.Substring(8)).replace("T", " ")

    } elseif ($row -like "# User@Host*")
    {
        $UserHost = $row.Substring(13, $row.IndexOf("Id:")-13)

        $Id = $row.Substring($row.IndexOf("Id:")+4)

    } elseif ($row -like "# Query_time*")
    {
        $QueryTime = $row.Substring(14, $row.IndexOf("Lock_time:")-14)

        $LockTime = $row.Substring($row.IndexOf("Lock_time:")+11, $row.IndexOf("Rows_sent:")-$row.IndexOf("Lock_time:")-11)

        $RowsSent = $row.Substring($row.IndexOf("Rows_sent:")+11, $row.IndexOf("Rows_examined:")-$row.IndexOf("Rows_sent:")-11)

        $RowsExamined = $row.Substring($row.IndexOf("Rows_examined:")+15)

    } elseif (-not ($row -like "Time                 Id Command    Argument*" -or $row -like "*started with:*" -or $row -like "Tcp port:*" -or $row -like "use *" -or $row -like "SET timestamp=*"))
    {

        $Statement = $Statement + $row + "
"
    }
}

# Prepare normalized SQL statement by replacing actual values in the query string with "?" to identify identical queries
$NormStatement = $Statement -replace("(\d+|\'.*?\')", "???") 

$Statement = $Statement.Substring( 0, [math]::min($Statement.Length, 16000) ) #cut off a very long string
$NormStatement = $NormStatement.Substring( 0, [math]::min($NormStatement.Length, 16000) ) #cut off a very long string

$Props = @{
    "QueryNum"        = 0
    "Time"            = $Time
    "GroupNum"        = 0
    "UserHost"        = $UserHost
    "Id"              = $Id
    "QueryTime"       = $QueryTime
    "LockTime"        = $LockTime
    "RowsSent"        = $RowsSent
    "RowsExamined"    = $RowsExamined
    "Statement"       = $Statement
    "NormStatement"   = $NormStatement
}
$QueryProps += New-Object PSObject -Property $Props

# Number each query in the result set
$QueryProps | Sort-Object Time | %{$i=1} {$_.QueryNum = $i; $i++} 

$Worksheet1 = $QueryProps





# Group parsed content by the normalized SQL statement and measure Min/Max/Avg values
$GroupByNormStmt = $QueryProps | Select-Object QueryNum, Time, UserHost, Id, QueryTime, LockTime, RowsSent, RowsExamined, NormStatement | Sort-Object Time | Group-Object NormStatement 


$QueryProps = @()

$MinTime = ""
$MaxTime = ""

$MinQueryTime = 0
$MaxQueryTime = 0
$AvgQueryTime = 0
$TotalQueryTime = 0

$MinLockTime = 0
$MaxLockTime = 0
$AvgLockTime = 0
$TotalLockTime = 0

$MinRowsExamined = 0
$MaxRowsExamined = 0
$AvgRowsExamined = 0
$TotalRowsExamined = 0

$MinRowsSent = 0
$MaxRowsSent = 0
$AvgRowsSent = 0
$TotalRowsSent = 0 

foreach ($Group in $GroupByNormStmt)
{
    $MinTime = ($Group.Group.Time | Measure-Object -Minimum).Minimum
    $MaxTime = ($Group.Group.Time | Measure-Object -Maximum).Maximum

    $MinQueryTime = [decimal]($Group.Group.QueryTime | Measure-Object -Minimum).Minimum
    $MaxQueryTime = [decimal]($Group.Group.QueryTime | Measure-Object -Maximum).Maximum
    $AvgQueryTime = [decimal]($Group.Group.QueryTime | Measure-Object -Average).Average
    $TotalQueryTime = [decimal]($Group.Group.QueryTime | Measure-Object -Sum).Sum

    $MinLockTime = [decimal]($Group.Group.LockTime | Measure-Object -Minimum).Minimum
    $MaxLockTime = [decimal]($Group.Group.LockTime | Measure-Object -Maximum).Maximum
    $AvgLockTime = [decimal]($Group.Group.LockTime | Measure-Object -Average).Average
    $TotalLockTime = [decimal]($Group.Group.LockTime | Measure-Object -Sum).Sum

    $MinRowsExamined = [decimal]($Group.Group.RowsExamined | Measure-Object -Minimum).Minimum
    $MaxRowsExamined = [decimal]($Group.Group.RowsExamined | Measure-Object -Maximum).Maximum
    $AvgRowsExamined = [decimal]($Group.Group.RowsExamined | Measure-Object -Average).Average
    $TotalRowsExamined = [decimal]($Group.Group.RowsExamined | Measure-Object -Sum).Sum

    $MinRowsSent = [decimal]($Group.Group.RowsSent | Measure-Object -Minimum).Minimum
    $MaxRowsSent = [decimal]($Group.Group.RowsSent | Measure-Object -Maximum).Maximum
    $AvgRowsSent = [decimal]($Group.Group.RowsSent | Measure-Object -Average).Average
    $TotalRowsSent = [decimal]($Group.Group.RowsSent | Measure-Object -Sum).Sum

    $QueryNums = ""

    foreach ($QueryNum in $Group.Group.QueryNum)
    {
        $QueryNums = $QueryNums + ", " + [string]$QueryNum
    }

    $Props = @{
        "GroupNum"         = 0
        "NormStatement"    = $Group.Name
        "QueryCount"       = $Group.Count

        "MinTime"          = $MinTime
        "MaxTime"          = $MaxTime
        "MinQueryTime"     = $MinQueryTime
        "MaxQueryTime"     = $MaxQueryTime
        "AvgQueryTime"     = $AvgQueryTime

        "TotalQueryTime"   = $TotalQueryTime
        "MinLockTime"      = $MinLockTime
        "MaxLockTime"      = $MaxLockTime
        "AvgLockTime"      = $AvgLockTime
        "TotalLockTime"    = $TotalLockTime

        "QueryNums"        = $QueryNums.TrimStart(", ")

        "MinRowsExamined"  = $MinRowsExamined
        "MaxRowsExamined"  = $MaxRowsExamined
        "AvgRowsExamined"  = $AvgRowsExamined
        "TotalRowsExamined" = $TotalRowsExamined

        "MinRowsSent"      = $MinRowsSent
        "MaxRowsSent"      = $MaxRowsSent
        "AvgRowsSent"      = $AvgRowsSent
        "TotalRowsSent"    = $TotalRowsSent
    }
    $QueryProps += New-Object PSObject -Property $Props

}

# Number each query in the result set
$QueryProps | Sort-Object MinTime | %{$i=1} {$_.GroupNum = $i; $i++} 

$Worksheet2 = $QueryProps

# Assign group number to the queries in the first worksheet
foreach ($Object in $Worksheet2)
{
    $Worksheet1 | %{ if ($_.NormStatement -eq $Object.NormStatement) { $_.GroupNum = $Object.GroupNum} } 
}




# Export results to Excel
$Worksheet1 | Select-Object QueryNum, Time, GroupNum, UserHost, Id, QueryTime, LockTime, RowsSent, RowsExamined, Statement | Sort-Object QueryNum | Export-Excel -Path $ReportFile -TableStyle Light11 -WorksheetName "OrderByTime" -Append -AutoSize -FreezePane 1,4    


$ResExls = $Worksheet2 | Select-Object GroupNum, NormStatement, QueryNums, QueryCount, MinTime, MaxTime, MinQueryTime, MaxQueryTime, AvgQueryTime, TotalQueryTime, MinLockTime, MaxLockTime, AvgLockTime, TotalLockTime, MinRowsExamined, MaxRowsExamined, AvgRowsExamined, TotalRowsExamined, MinRowsSent, MaxRowsSent, AvgRowsSent, TotalRowsSent | Export-Excel -Path $ReportFile -TableStyle Light11 -WorksheetName "GroupByNormStatement" -Append -AutoSize -FreezePane 1,3 -PassThru

$Sheet = $ResExls.Workbook.Worksheets["GroupByNormStatement"]

Set-Column -Worksheet $sheet -Column 2 -Width 100 -Bold
Set-Column -Worksheet $sheet -Column 3 -Width 40 -HorizontalAlignment left

$Sheet = $ResExls.Workbook.Worksheets["OrderByTime"]

Set-Column -Worksheet $sheet -Column 2 -Bold
    
Close-ExcelPackage $ResExls –Show
```

Answer (score -4):

You could use a spreadsheet if you can parse the data into individual fields, then sum by query and sort by count of executions and average.  Y'know... Normal data analysis stuff.

If you need to, write a regex based application to split the log up into CSV.  While you're at it, you could even write a concordance engine for the log names, check averages, and make the tool you're after.

Of course, someone is likely to come in and say "Duh, use 'analysisMySQLProDemon40005K+!'" after I post this.